# PHP Login System - Give username small, when logged in username like in Database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I've finished here a login system in php with MySQL, but I want now that when I write my username in the `login.php` it also can be in small letters, and when I'm logged in, that my username will be changed to the original username, how it's registered in the database.

```
<?php

  session_start();

  if(isset($_SESSION["username"]))

    header("location:h_inc/h_pages/me.php");

    if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

      if(empty($_POST["username"]) || empty($_POST["password"])){
        $empty_fields = array();
        $empty_fields['error'] = "<font color=\"red\">Please fill all fields.</font>";

      }else{
        if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"])."' AND password = '".mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST["password"]))."' AND rank = '9'")) > 0){
          $empty_fields['true'] = "<font color=\"green\">You are now logged in.</font>";

          $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
          $_SESSION["password"] = md5($_POST["password"]);

          echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.location.href = 'index.php';</script>";
        }else{
          $empty_fields['error'] = "<font color=\"red\">Your datas are incorrect.</font>";
        }
      }
    }

?>
```

Comment: replace *$_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];* with date username from result

Comment: Before you continue and fully write your project in mysql_*, please considder using mysqli_* or PDO since mysql_* is deprecated..

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mysql_num_rows fetch the result from your query and use the value therein to display the username.

As @Naruto pointed out in the comments: Think about switching to PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Return your query values ,then get your original name from return value and assign it in session variable

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["username"])."' AND password = '".mysql_real_escape_string(md5($_POST["password"]))."' AND rank = '9'");
    if($result) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $username = $row["username"];
    }
     $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
     $_SESSION["password"] = md5($_POST["password"]);
     echo "<script type='text/javascript'> window.location.href = 'index.php';</script>";
    }else{
          $empty_fields['error'] = "<font color=\"red\">Your datas are incorrect.</font>";
        }
```